# Git bash is working in windows terminal, but not in visual studio code

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, command-line, git-bash

so this is exactly what it sounds like.
In a visual studio code terminal I type "bash", and it says

"bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- bash ./build.sh buildrun Debug vscode
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
  ```

but if I run it in the windows terminal, it works perfectly fine, it just works like how its supposed to.

I will attach an image for a better explenation.[image: The issue]

( This might be a very simple fix, but i dont know what to try, so im desperate )

I tried adding the bash directory to the system path (whenever it wasnt working in the terminal, and it fixed that), I thought it would also fix the visual studio code terminal, but it did not. I dont know what else to try.

Comment: After you added bash to the system path, did you restart vscode? The environment variable wouldn't take effect unless the parent process also picked up the env. When in doubt, log out of windows and back in again.

Comment: @selbie i restarted my pc and restarted vscode multiple times to no avail

Comment: I don't know much about VSC, but the error message says that the terminal does not run bash, but probably Powershell. I suggest that you configure VSC to start bash when you open a terminal. With this, your question is about VSC configuration and should be asked at [su], not Stackoverflow.

Comment: @user1934428 the VSC terminal is powershell, at least it says it is.

Comment: If I remember darkly my time with playing around with VSC, powershell is the default, but you can configure various terminal configurations using different shells. If you want to stick with powershell, but from PS invoke bash as external program, your question boils down how to configure powershell so that you can do so. This too is a question suitable for [su]. Perhaps your PATH is wrong. Does it work if you invoke bash by providing its absolute path?

Comment: what options did you take for adding programs to the system path when installing Git For Windows? Please also show us the output of printing the `PATH` variable in both the VS Code integrated terminal and your external PowerShell terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot and error message shows you're trying to launch Git Bash from PowerShell. You need to select it from the VSCode Terminal list. You shouldn't need to alter any `PATH` values.

[image: VSCode Terminal Options with Git Bash]

You can see the default Git Bash color scheme appear with the terminal name in the sidebar.

[image: VSCode Terminal with Git Bash]

Can you see Git Bash in the terminal option list? Can you select that? You can change the default Terminal using the setting `Terminal Select Default Profile`.